# "She died by yesterday" vs "She died yesterday"

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context

A lady in a british movie is talking about her neighbour's death and she says: **"She died by yesterday**."

I have never seen or heard "**by yesterday**" and I am not sure if it is correct in formal English.

So my question is: Why does she say **"She died by yesterday**", while "**She died yesterday"** would be good enough.

Thanks

Here is the link of movie where the sentence is used. Please see the 10:05 (minute-seconds)
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NOsOFGG5Vc4

Comment: I strongly suspect that you misheard.

Comment: Assuming that's what was actually said, it's nonstandard. While it's understandable, a more natural way of expressing the same thing would be: *She was alive until yesterday.* (Assuming it was already known that she had died, that is.)

Comment: Michael Harvey, see and hear it yourself. It also has subtitles. Please see the 10:05 (minute-seconds) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NOsOFGG5Vc4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The subtitles are wrong; the spoken words are "She died but yesterday", 'but' is clearly audible to a native speaker, and are also present in the script. "But yesterday" means "only yesterday".

[Part of script](http://SOPHY%20She%20died%20but%20yesterday)

Comment: Ohhhhh. This was one of the newest things in the English language I have never heard before. thank you Michael. I appreciate your contribution. It has really really been a great contribution to my English. I have been learning English for years and I have never seen the word "but" can also be used in this way which meant "only". Thank you very much. Now the sentence makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

I don't recall ever having heard "by yesterday " used in that way, or in any similar way.  I would favor

> She died yesterday.

Which is certainly an utterly standard usage.

Once could say

> She expected to be done by yesterday.

or any similar use. I am imagine a forensic investigator, say a character on CSI, saying

> From the temperature of the body, she must have died by yesterday.

meaning "no later than yesterday". Although "...been dead by yesterday" would be a more natural usage.